# How to parse json text data with python

Tags: python, json

I need to make a request to the api of my client, and the api returns this data:

```
[6,0,'VT3zrYA',5,'USUeZWA',5,0,0,0,0,0,4,0,0,0,2,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,2,0,1,["portale.titolari.client.config.ShoulderDTO/4121330600","java.util.HashSet/3273092938","MATTEO SBRAGIA","java.util.ArrayList/4159755760","java.util.Date/3385151746","MATTEO"],0,7]
```

How can I parse this data and extract the following fields :

```
MATTEO SBRAGIA
MATTEO
```

I've tried this code, but it's not working :

```
data = json.load(output_data)
pprint data
```

Comment: what is the result of your print statement? it also doesn't really look like your data is in json format....

Comment: Does the incoming record have a fixed number of fields? Show us what you've tried?

Comment: yes is same position every time

Comment: @Matt i want to extract names like my example

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. What is the output of your `print data` command?

Comment: Isn't the data just a list? Why bother to convert it to json?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This in fact is not a valid JSON string because it contains single quotes `'`. You can replace all single quotes with double quotes and then parse the string but it's a question whether this was intentional or a mistake:

```
import json

s = '[6,0,\'VT3zrYA\',5,\'USUeZWA\',5,0,0,0,0,0,4,0,0,0,2,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,2,0,1,["portale.titolari.client.config.ShoulderDTO/4121330600","java.util.HashSet/3273092938","MATTEO SBRAGIA","java.util.ArrayList/4159755760","java.util.Date/3385151746","MATTEO"],0,7]'

data = json.loads(s.replace("\'", '"'))

print(data[26][2])
print(data[26][5])
```

prints:

```
$ python test.py 
MATTEO SBRAGIA
MATTEO
```